# Laravel 5.8 + Vue2JS Session and Old values in component

Tags: laravel, vue-component

I have question about normal laravel multi form with post action as method based on laravel session. I added in this form component of vue, which is simple city autocomplete. I want load to inputs into fields of this component from session (session()), or old (old()) values, if session exist i want to load from session city and province, but if session doesnt exist, but old laravel values exist I want to load them in this component form, if they doesnt exist, leave fields empty. What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Get the session and pass a default which would be the old value.

```
$data = session('session_data_key', $old_value); // however you get the old value is up to you.
```

Pass it down to your view. If no session is set on the server, it will use the default (if default is null it will not set the auto-complete).

UPDATE
If you are using axios to make calls to a laravel app, before loading the form component (in mounted() {}) do a call to axios to get the value of (session or old value). This is what you'll load into the form.

```
axios.get('/api/load_dafault').then(resp => {
     this.defaultValueToBePassedToField = resp.data.value;
});
```

The endpoint '/api/load_dafault' or whatever yours is named, will have it's controller like so:

```
public function loadDefaults()
{
    $old_value = ... // however you get it is up to you.
    $data = session('session_data_key', $old_value);
}
```

Do not forget to ensure you set the routes.

Comment: Okay, but how to pass it into Vue component? Where should I place it?